# I was taking a challenge

Tags: javascript

I was taking a challenge and one of the questions seems like I got the right answer but it wouldn't pass. Need help understanding why it didn't.

Challenge: Add a method to the Person's prototype called "shoutName" that returns the person's name in all uppercase letters.

```
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.shoutName = function() {
        name.toUpperCase();
        return '"' + name.toUpperCase()+'"'
    }
}

/* Do not modify the code below this line */

const john = new Person('John');
console.log(john.shoutName(), '<-- should be "JOHN" ');
```

Comment: Please copy the code, **as text**, not as an image, into your question.  That way we can run it and work on it.

Comment: You should post your code in text as mentioned by @Amy. The answer to your question is that you did not modify the prototype but instead added an instance property. Correct solution probably would have been: `Person.prototype.shoutName = function() {return this.name.toUpperCase();}`.

Comment: Thank you for all of your help and suggestion

Answer (score 1):

The question said to add a function to the constructor's prototype.

You didn't do that. You modified the constructor to dynamically add the function to the instance as the instance was created.

```
Person.prototype.shoutName = function () {
    return this.name.toUpperCase();
}
```

Your function also wrapped the resulting value in quotes, which the question didn't ask you to do.

Comment: Thank you for all of your help and suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

From your tiny picture, I noticed that your code was:

```
return '"' + name.toUpperCase() + '"';
```

Not sure why you added the quotes, just `return this.name.toUpperCase();` and it should work fine. You should be referencing *this* object's property, rather than the input value of just `name`.

Also, having `name.toUpperCase();` on a line by itself does **nothing**. Unnecessary calculations since that function returns a value that you're not assigning.

Comment: Thank you for all of your help and suggestion